# Electron How to create menus in the main process?

Tags: javascript, electron

The Electron documentation discusses menu creation only within the Renderer process.  Since the application menu bar (in my case at least) will be static for my application it would be preferable to create just once once from the Main Process.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, [the documentation](https://github.com/atom/electron/blob/master/docs/api/menu.md) says that it's designed to be used in the Main process, although you can use it in Renderer with the `remote` module:

> This module is a main process module which can be used in a render process via the `remote` module.

So, wherever you have your Main process, you just need to do:

```
const electron = require('electron');
const Menu = electron.Menu;

mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({width: 800, height: 600});

var menu = new Menu();

// Prepare your menu's content ...

Menu.setApplicationMenu(menu);
```

Comment: this is unhelpful.  That very documentation is on how to create a menu from within the render process as I mentioned in my original question.

Comment: I just added a brief code snippet that should clear your doubts :)